# php upload file ask whether to overwrite existing file or not

Tags: file, overwrite, uploading

I am uploading files using PHP. I want to achieve the following target. While uploading the file it checks whether the file already exists on target destination or not if it continues then it prompts the user do you want to overwrite the existing file or not. If the user hit yes, it overwrites else don't.

Comment: What have you got so far? please share your code or snippet

Comment: i have just uploaded the files using function move_uploaded_file. but have no idea of implementing the ask for overwrite files logic

Comment: Please add all the info to the question so people who come along and want to help don't need to read the comments for basic details. I myself am completely clueless in PHP...